# DateTime Picker using SLDS

Tags: datetime, slds, date-picker

I want to display a Datetime picker using Lightning Design System.
So far, I am just able to display Date picker using SLDS and Appiphony Lightning JS.
More details : [Date picker using Appiphony Lightning JS](http://aljs.appiphony.com/#!/datepickers)

But anyone could please help me with the time component using SLDS, so that I would be able to construct Datetime picker in SLDS.

Comment: I just used the example date picker CSS on the lightning website with type="date" and built in datepicker appeared. You will have to store vale selected and parse to date though

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think that you can go with two approaches nowadays.

First one (easier, recommended)

Using lightning:input as it is currently developed by salesforce component for lightning.

Easy peasy lemon squeezy:

```
<lightning:input type="datetime" name="input1" label="Enter a date/time value" />
```

Second approach which lets you manually customize everything but with slds classes is descirbed in the SLDS documentation.

[Date Picker SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/datetime-picker/)

And full copy paste in case if reference will be down

```
<div style="height: 25rem;">
  <div class="slds-form slds-form--compound">
    <fieldset class="slds-form-element">
      <legend class="slds-form-element__label">Date and Time</legend>
      <div class="slds-form-element__group">
        <div class="slds-form-element__row">
          <div class="slds-form-element slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="date-input-id">Date</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right">
              <input type="text" id="date-input-id" placeholder=" " class="slds-input" value="06/24/2014" />
              <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-input__icon slds-input__icon--right" title="Select a date">
                <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                  <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#event" />
                </svg>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select a date</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Date picker: June" class="slds-datepicker slds-dropdown slds-dropdown_left" role="dialog">
              <div class="slds-datepicker__filter slds-grid">
                <div class="slds-datepicker__filter_month slds-grid slds-grid_align-spread slds-grow">
                  <div class="slds-align-middle">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Previous Month">
                      <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#left" />
                      </svg>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Previous Month</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <h2 aria-atomic="true" aria-live="assertive" class="slds-align-middle" id="month">June</h2>
                  <div class="slds-align-middle">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-container" title="Next Month">
                      <svg class="slds-button__icon" aria-hidden="true">
                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#right" />
                      </svg>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Next Month</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-shrink-none">
                  <label class="slds-assistive-text" for="select-01">Pick a Year</label>
                  <div class="slds-select_container">
                    <select class="slds-select" id="select-01">
                      <option>2014</option>
                      <option>2015</option>
                      <option>2016</option>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <table aria-labelledby="month" aria-multiselectable="true" class="slds-datepicker__month" role="grid">
                <thead>
                  <tr id="weekdays">
                    <th id="Sunday" scope="col">
                      <abbr title="Sunday">Sun</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th id="Monday" scope="col">
                      <abbr title="Monday">Mon</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th id="Tuesday" scope="col">
                      <abbr title="Tuesday">Tue</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th id="Wednesday" scope="col">
                      <abbr title="Wednesday">Wed</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th id="Thursday" scope="col">
                      <abbr title="Thursday">Thu</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th id="Friday" scope="col">
                      <abbr title="Friday">Fri</abbr>
                    </th>
                    <th id="Saturday" scope="col">
                      <abbr title="Saturday">Sat</abbr>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td aria-disabled="true" aria-selected="false" class="slds-disabled-text" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">31</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell" tabindex="0">
                      <span class="slds-day">1</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">2</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">3</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">4</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">5</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">6</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">7</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">8</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">9</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">10</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">11</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">12</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">13</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">14</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">15</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">16</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">17</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" aria-current="date" class="slds-is-today" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">18</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">19</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">20</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="slds-has-multi-selection">
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">21</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">22</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">23</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="true" class="slds-is-selected" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">24</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" class="" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">25</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">26</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">27</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="">
                    <td aria-selected="false" class="" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">28</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">29</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-selected="false" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">30</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-disabled="true" aria-selected="false" class="slds-disabled-text" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">1</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-disabled="true" aria-selected="false" class="slds-disabled-text" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">2</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-disabled="true" aria-selected="false" class="slds-disabled-text" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">3</span>
                    </td>
                    <td aria-disabled="true" aria-selected="false" class="slds-disabled-text" role="gridcell">
                      <span class="slds-day">4</span>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button class="slds-button slds-align_absolute-center slds-text-link">Today</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-form-element">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="combobox-unique-id-4">Time</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
              <div class="slds-combobox_container">
                <div class="slds-combobox slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger_click slds-is-open slds-combobox-picklist slds-timepicker" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="listbox" role="combobox">
                  <div class="slds-combobox__form-element slds-input-has-icon slds-input-has-icon_right" role="none">
                    <input type="text" class="slds-input slds-combobox__input slds-combobox__input-value" id="combobox-unique-id-4" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="listbox-unique-id" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" placeholder=" " value="8:00am"
                    />
                    <span class="slds-icon_container slds-icon-utility-clock slds-input__icon slds-input__icon_right" title="Select a time">
                      <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-icon-text-default" aria-hidden="true">
                        <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#clock" />
                      </svg>
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">Select a time</span>
                    </span>
                  </div>
                  <div id="listbox-unique-id" role="listbox">
                    <ul class="slds-listbox slds-listbox_vertical slds-dropdown slds-dropdown--fluid slds-dropdown--length-5" role="presentation">
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-01" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="6:00am"> 6:00am</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-02" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="7:00am"> 7:00am</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-03" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center slds-is-selected" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="8:00am">
                              <span class="slds-assistive-text">Current Selection:</span> 8:00am</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-04" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="9:00am"> 9:00am</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-05" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="10:00am"> 10:00am</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-06" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="11:00am"> 11:00am</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-07" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="12:00pm"> 12:00pm</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-08" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="1:00pm"> 1:00pm</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-09" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="2:00pm"> 2:00pm</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-10" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="3:00pm"> 3:00pm</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-11" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="4:00pm"> 4:00pm</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                      <li role="presentation" class="slds-listbox__item">
                        <div id="listbox-option-unique-id-12" class="slds-media slds-listbox__option slds-listbox__option_plain slds-media_small slds-media_center" role="option">
                          <span class="slds-media__figure">
                            <svg class="slds-icon slds-icon_x-small slds-listbox__icon-selected" aria-hidden="true">
                              <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#check" />
                            </svg>
                          </span>
                          <span class="slds-media__body">
                            <span class="slds-truncate" title="5:00pm"> 5:00pm</span>
                          </span>
                        </div>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

It would be best to handle these with two separate inputs, similar to how Lightning Experience displays a datetime field on the UI. A date picker component is displayed in one field, and a time input appears adjacent to it, allowing for the user to focus on the field to type a date or select from a list (by clicking the clock icon).

http://recordit.co/mAUraZjhcf

Comment: SFSE doesn't support gif uploads.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:inputDateTime/example

ui:inputDateTime has both date and time field.

Comment: the ui:* components are deprecated in aura and not available in lwc